# Is saying 'This statement is true' a logically valid statement?

Tags: logic

I understand how 'This statement is false' is not logically valid, but what about 'This statement is true'? I've always heard self-referential statements are not logically sound, but I can't really give a great explanation for why this one would not be. Anyone have a good argument one way or the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be consistently assigned either "true" or "false".

Interestingly enough, "this statement is provable" is provable (or more precisely, in a suitable formal system to which Gödel's theorems apply,
a statement which asserts its own provability is in fact provable).
See [Löb's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem)

Comment: Very Nice reference